# Construction of Circles Pass Through a Given Point and Touch Two Given Lines

Tags: euclidean-geometry, geometric-construction

**Problem:** We are given two (intersecting) lines, say $L_1$ and $L_2$ (in $xy$ plane). And we are given a point, say $P$, not lying any on the lines. Construct the circles that pass through $P$ and touch the given lines.

It is clear that the centres of the circles lie on angle bisector of the lines. But I am not able to precisely locate the centre.

Please help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find the centre of a circle passing through a known point and tangential to two known lines](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/43854/find-the-centre-of-a-circle-passing-through-a-known-point-and-tangential-to-two). [The answer by Jyrki Lahtonen](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/43957/580448)  is a construction by ruler + compass.

Comment: The method Jyrki Lahtonen wrote uses homothety transformation. Another construction is given in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_cases_of_Apollonius%27_problem#Type_3:_One_point,_two_lines) as "Type 3: One point, two lines" of Apollonius' problem.

Comment: @Apass.Jack Thanks! It helped.